# For loop and pagination

Tags: javascript, for-loop, pagination

I have a big array of objects and i want to show them in many pages and limit the number shown each page to 4 what would be the correct way to do it?

```
let i,j,temparray,chunk = 5;
  for (i=0,j=this.yorumlar.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
      temparray = this.yorumlar.slice(i,i+chunk);
    this.one = temparray
  }
```

this code slices my array in pieces of 4 but then how can I use these slices here this.one gives me only the first 4 how can I get rest of pieces

Comment: Which framework are you using? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I use Vue but what I actually need is a way to slice my array to pieces then I want to loop that one. Would this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paginate Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761068/paginate-javascript-array)

Comment: No sry, I dont think I approach this right way I should work on this more.